# Multiple Inner Join Alias Not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax for SQL joins. This is my query below.

```
SELECT users.family_name, users.given_name, users.bio, votes_stories.*, stories.* \
    FROM stories \
    INNER JOIN users \
      ON users.id=stories.author_id \
    INNER JOIN votes_stories.type AS vote_type \ // <--- error occurs here. 
      ON votes_stories.story_id=stories.id \
      AND votes_stories.user_id=$1
```

Error: error: relation "votes_stories.type" does not exist

I'd like to rename `vote_stories.type` to `vote_type`

Comment: If you alias your table you need to use that alias in the on clause also.

Comment: Also `votes_stories.type` is a column, not a table. Presumably you meant to just join `votes_stories`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend something like this:

```
SELECT u.family_name, u.given_name, u.bio, vs.type AS vote_type
FROM stories s INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = s.author_id INNER JOIN
     votes_stories vs
     ON vs.story_id = s.id AND
        vs.user_id = $1;
```

The columns you want to select go in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT users.family_name, users.given_name, users.bio, vote_type.*, stories.*
FROM stories
JOIN users ON users.id=stories.author_id
JOIN vote_type.type AS vote_type ON vote_type.story_id=stories.id AND vote_type.user_id=$1
```